# Nativebase - how to show datepicker when clicking input?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using **NativeBase** components. I have `Form` with the following field:

```
       <Item floatingLabel last>
          <Label>Buy dateі</Label>
          <DatePicker
            defaultDate={buyTime}
            locale={"en"}
            modalTransparent={false}
            animationType={"fade"}
            androidMode={"default"}
            placeHolderText="Change buy date"
            textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
            placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
            onDateChange={this.handleBuyTimeChange}
            disabled={false}
            ref={component => (this.buyTimePicker = component)}
          />
          <Input
            value={buyTime.toString().substr(4, 12)}
            onPress={() => {
              this.buyTimePicker.showDatePicker();
            }}
          />
        </Item>
```

But clicking on `Input` doesn't trigger `DatePicker`. How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize nativebase datepicker with your own input component and if you insist  to you can use any 3rd party library for eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker.