# How to call a method of a component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using native-base datepicker and want to call the ShowDatePicker method from outside the component.  It owuld be something like this except:

1. This.DatePicker doesnt exist
2. I dont know if that method is exposed, or how to reach it..

i think it has something to do with using refs?

Thank you!

```
<Content>
  <Button onPress={this.DatePicker.showDatePicker}>
  <DatePicker props}/>
</Content>
```

DatePicker source code: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/DatePicker.js

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have to ref it just like the another answer says, as follows

```
<Content>
  <Button onPress={this.DatePicker.showDatePicker}>
  <DatePicker ref={ref => this.DatePicker = ref } {...this.props}/>
</Content>
```

However this will not fix your issue unless `DatePicker` component takes a props as `ref`. In short, even if you do that in your component, you will not have access to the `showDatePicker`.
Rather trying to do so, you can do this in two way (assuming you are trying to showhide component on button click.
Option 1: 
Use a prop `showDatePicker` which will show hide the component.
For ex,

```
<Content>
  <Button onPress={this.setState({showHide: !this.state.showHide})}>
  <DatePicker showDatePicker={this.state.showHide}  {...this.props} />
</Content>
```

then in `DatePicker` use this prop to do some logic.
Or Option 2,
Use conditional operator to show hide the whole component. w
For ex,

```
<Content>
  <Button onPress={this.setState({showHide: !this.state.showHide})}>
  {this.state.showHide && <DatePicker {...this.props} />}
</Content>
```

Let me know if you wanted to do something else, I will update the answer.

EDIT:
Looking at your code in gist.github.com/fotoflo/13b9dcf2a078ff49abaf7dccd040e179, I figured what you are trying to do.
In short, you trying to show datepicker on click of a button. Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment looking at [Nativebase - how to show datepicker when clicking input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047385/nativebase-how-to-show-datepicker-when-clicking-input) and the documentation https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref.
If you really wanna have it, you should think about these possible solution, 
Option 1: fork `native-base` do your manipulation and use the datepicker or even submit the PR to `native-base` for future use.
Option2: you can use any 3rd party library for eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker.
Or my favourite option 3:

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Modal, View, Platform, DatePickerIOS, DatePickerAndroid } from 'react-native';

state = {
      currentDate: date,
      showiOSDatePicker: false,
      chosenDate: date,
      formattedDate
}

showDatePicker = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      this.setState({
        showiOSDatePicker: true
      });
    } else {
      const { chosenDate, currentDate } = this.state;
      try {
        const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
          date: chosenDate,
          maxDate: currentDate
        });
        if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
          const dateSelected = new Date(year, month, day);
          const formattedDate = this.getFormattedDate(dateSelected)
          this.setState({chosenDate: dateSelected, formattedDate});
          console.log(formattedDate)
        }
      } catch ({code, message}) {
        console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
      }
    }
  }

render() {
const { showiOSDatePicker } = this.state;
  return (
    <View>
       {showiOSDatePicker &&
          <Modal
            animationType="fade"
            transparent
            visible={showiOSDatePicker}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
            <View
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center'
              }}
            >
              <View style={{
                margin: 22,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(240,240,240,1)'
              }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(87,191,229,1)',
                    borderBottomWidth: 2,
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    height: 70,
                    paddingRight: 20
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{
                    color: 'rgba(40,176,226,1)',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    paddingLeft: 20
                  }}>
                    {formattedDate}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <DatePickerIOS
                  date={chosenDate}
                  onDateChange={this.setDate}
                  maximumDate={currentDate}
                  mode="date"
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    borderTopColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                    borderTopWidth: 1,
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    height: 50
                  }}
                  onPress={this.onCloseDatePicker}
                >
                  <Text>
                    Done
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        }
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDatePicker}>
          <Text>Show Date</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

  );

}
```

Let me know if this make sense, or I will put together a working example in https://snack.expo.io/
Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answerActually for 1) I’m not sure how refs work or how to unpack that syntax for the ref or how this.DatePicker variable comes into existence...  so looking at option 2, show/hide the whole comportment will only show hide it in its hidden state (aka you can see the placeholder, not the picking state) so I really need to change theinternal stare show/hide state... I guess I could pass that state down and edit the open source component to optionally take it

Comment: the first way almost works, howevr i get an error - this.setState is not a function. I think the context of "this" is not running inside the ref maybe?

Comment: Can you explain me whats the end goal? On button click show the date picker, and another button click to disable the date picker? I will suggest you a working example based on that.

Comment: Hi, here is a Gist - gist.github.com/fotoflo/13b9dcf2a078ff49abaf7dccd040e179  - you can see the date, and once you select the date, you can see how many years ago it was, if that number is wrong, you can click it to select again... currently the second click gets an error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give a ref to DatePicker

```
<Content>
  <Button onPress={this.DatePicker.showDatePicker}>
  <DatePicker ref={ref => this.DatePicker = ref } props}/>
</Content>
```

Comment: However, i get an error - this.setState is not a function. i think the context of "this" is not running inside the ref maybe?

Comment: that's enough to work. Can you please share your current code so I can check it

Comment: Hi, here is a Gist - gist.github.com/fotoflo/13b9dcf2a078ff49abaf7dccd040e179  - you can see the date, and once you select the date, you can see how many years ago it was, if that number is wrong, you can click it to select again... currently the second click gets an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was my solution:

NativeBase DatePicker:

```
 <DatePicker
              defaultDate={new Date(2018, 4, 4)}
              minimumDate={new Date(2018, 1, 1)}
              maximumDate={new Date(2020, 12, 31)}
              locale={"es"}
              timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
              modalTransparent={true}
              animationType={"fade"}
              androidMode={"default"}
              placeHolderText="Select date"
              textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
              placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
              onDateChange={this.setDate.bind(this)}
              disabled={false}
              ref={c => this._datePicker = (c) } 
            />
```

And with this you can open the datePicker:

```
 <Button onPress={()=>{ this._datePicker.setState({modalVisible:true})}}>
   <Text>
  showDatePicker
  </Text>
</Button>
```

I hope it helps